# Video flickering when recording a screen with a mobile phone

Tags: iphone, mobile, screenshot

When recording a computer screen straight with a mobile phone, there are sometimes colored spots to see in the recorded material. I know that when recording CRT displays, the flickering was caused by different refresh rates between recording device and playing device. Can I prevent the flickering/discoloration in spots on a mobile phone?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment I guess but I don't have enough rep.

What kind of monitor are you using?

My iPhone records my 27" Retina 5k monitor just fine.

My guess is you have an LCD monitor and you are having polarizing issues (

)

Comment: It does not matter. It's with every monitor (LCD). Just open Instagram and you can see tons of people taking pictures of their monitor. That's what I meant.

Comment: Taking a picture is slightly different from taking video on your phone. Resolution is much higher for photo than video - which could cause issues - because you are taking pictures of points of light - usually 1920 lights by 1080 lights. If your resolution can "resolve" all of these points individually - from an angle - it will have strange effects.

Comment: It does not matter if video or photo. Essentially, I mean this. https://www.instagram.com/p/_I-XPQLrjc/ Is this just lighting? https://www.periscope.tv/heuteplus/1BRJjDpPADBKw (At minute 00:53) It's clear that they've recorded straight from a monitor but I wonder why they chose this setup and not improve the visual appearance.